# Al entrar en vim se me activa el replace

Tags: linux, debian, vim

tengo un problema con vim, al entrar a vim me sale por defecto el replace, en vez el modo 0 para poder moverme y demas, por lo que al moverme siempre sobreescribo algo y tengo que hacer undo y escape para poner el modo normal, como puedo cambiar eso?? he eliminado el vimrc pero nada, sigue igual, que deberia de hacer para solucionarlo?? no se si hay alguna forma de editar eso desde el vimrc o algo, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Lo usas en el modo terminal? ¿Que terminal usas?

Comment: uso la terminal de windows, y tengo instalado zsh

Comment: Francamente nunca me había pasado ni en windows ni en linux, tal ve sea algo de zsh, pero no tengo el gusto de conocerlo. Revisate esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388353/vim-changes-into-replace-mode-on-startup a ver si te sirve.

Comment: okey muchas gracias por las aportaciones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logré solucionarlo con este código:

```
set noek and nnoremap <silent> <esc> <esc>:noh<cr>
```

Comment: Pero me pasa lo mismo si entro como sudo

Comment: Es lógico, cuando entras con sudo, estas entrando con otro usuario (root), con lo cual deberías repetir la configuración que hayas hecho eventualmente en el usuario estándar.